# What order of files is used for hashing pieces in torrent

Tags: sorting, bittorrent, specifications

Torrent specification says for "peices" field:

> pieces: string consisting of the concatenation of all 20-byte SHA1 hash values, one per piece

But in case of directory there are multiple files. So to be broken to pieces files must be taken in some order. When I use bencode editor on existing torrents I see files come definitely not in alphabetical order, nor they comes in last modification order. But two different tools generate torrents with identical hashes. So there must be some defined order. But I still cannot find this in torrent specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to piece hashes, the metafile creation sees the content as one big blob, as if the files from info.files were concatenated. The order *in* info.files is a choice of the client, µTorrent defaults to "order by size" since quite a few versions, other clients sort by relative path names.

Info hashes can and will differ when different creators choose different file orders, just like with piece size choices.

Comment: Can confirm the big blob.
Proof: create 2 files with just the content "test" and create a torrent from it. In the torrent the pieces sha1 will be "51abb9636078defbf888d8457a7c76f85c8f114c". The Sha1 of an individual file will be "a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3". Now create a new file with the content "testtest" and sha1sum it. The result will be again "51abb9636078defbf888d8457a7c76f85c8f114c" as it was in the .torrent file with two single files